# Show and Hide using an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the code below I'm looking to change the "Hide me" and "Show me" to an image.
If I just add the image tags in the place of the strings I am getting the string of the image tags and not the image, can it be done here?

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {

   var show; // declare variable to hold show/hide state

   $(".apps .thebody").hide();

   $(".showme a").click(function(event) { // show/hide apps

     if (!show) {
       showhide($(this), "Hide me", true);
     } // Need to change the "Hide me" to an image, <img src="images/hide.png" height="41" width="45">
     else {
       showhide($(this), "Show me", false);
     } //  Need to change the "Show me" to an image, <img src="images/show.png" height="41" width="45">

     return false; // u know: disable usual link click function

     function showhide(what, swaptext, swapstate) {
       $(what).parents(".showme").prev(".thebody").toggle('fast');
       $(what).text(swaptext);
       show = swapstate; // pass the current state to
     }
   });

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="apps">
  <div class="thebody">

    <div style="font-size: 11px">
      My stuff will be here...
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="showme">
    <a href='' title='Show App'>
      <img src="images/show.png" height="41" width="45">
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {

   var show; // declare variable to hold show/hide state

   $(".apps .thebody").hide();

   $(".showme a").click(function(event) { // show/hide apps

     if (!show) {
       showhide($(this), "<img src='images/show.png' height='41' width='45'>", true);
     } // Need to change the "Hide me" to an image, <img src="images/hide.png" height="41" width="45">
     else {
       showhide($(this), "<img src='images/show.png' height='41' width='45'>", false);
     } //  Need to change the "Show me" to an image, <img src="images/show.png" height="41" width="45">

     return false; // u know: disable usual link click function

     function showhide(what, swaptext, swapstate) {
       $(".thebody").toggle('fast');
       $(what).html(swaptext);
       show = swapstate; // pass the current state to
     }
   });

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="apps">
  
  <div class="showme">
    <a href='' title='Show App'>
      <img src="images/show.png" height="41" width="45">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="thebody">

    <div style="font-size: 11px">
      My stuff will be here...
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

What I edited:

1. Change text to IMG tag
2. Use "html" instead of "text". `text` will render to inner text while `html` will render to HTML.

Comment: How would I force the content (My stuff will be here... ) to show under the clicked image and not on top of it?

Comment: @Andre look at my edited. Actually your Javascript code is not well structured. But maybe this is necessary so I didn't touch it's structure.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change one line, then start using the image tags again.

Change this:

```
$(what).text(swaptext);
```

To this...

```
$(what).html(swaptext);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simpify your code, into something like this (in which your 'image' is within your css, and not your html/etc):

```js
$('.hideShow').click(function(){
$('.toggleMe').slideToggle();
$('.hideShow').toggleClass("newClass");
});
```

```css
img{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background:url("http://placekitten.com/g/300/300"); 
}
.newClass{
  background-image:url("http://placekitten.com/g/200/200");
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggleMe">im toggling!!!</div>
<img src="" class="hideShow" />
```

If you wanted, you wouldn't even have to have the `img` tag for this one! An ordingary div would do (so long as you apply the class "hideShow")